# what do I need to know to get started in HPC?

Tags: hpc, cloud-computing

I have a huge interest in HPC, cloud computing and quantum computing since years. I'm currently a CS student with bachelor degree and I only have some basic knowledge about HPC from online articles and youtube videos on HPC. I have applied for a couple of internships and I have an interview next week in research lab.

I would like to know how should I prepare for this internship and for the interview? What do I need to know in advance?

P.S: I really hope my question is not off-topic, I checked the "What types of questions should I avoid asking?" section and could not find anything against my question.

Thanks in advance for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to take relevant courses but it may be late for that. There are two sides to HPC, the software optimization/parallelization/technology side and the Mathematics side. On the software optimization/parallelization/technology side there are MPI, OpenMP, CUDA and a lot of other technologies and their combinations. On the Mathematics side, you have techniques like multigrid preconditioners, HX preconditioners, fast multipole solvers and more.

The idea of HPC is simple, you do not want to waste any resources. To achieve that you do whatever is necessary. I will suggest you to check out XSEDE, PRACE, ComputeCanada (depending on where you are in Canada, SciNet, Westgrid and other consortiums might be available too). Every single one of them offer summer schools, trainings and online courses.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering my question! That's the kind of answer I needed. I just wanted a general idea of what I need to look for. The people who offered me an interview next week do not expect me to have prior knowledge, but they expect me to have an understanding of how HPC works in general and what kind of software is used. I live in Europe, but I will look for similar options to the ones you suggested. Thanks again

Comment: PRACE is the HPC consortium of European Union and they collaborate with XSEDE (US Consortium) a lot. You should have access to both of their educational resources.